# Is it possible to publish a movie from iMovie to youtube if you have two factor authentication on?

Tags: imovie, youtube

I want to publish a movie I made in iMovie to youtube but i have 2 factor authentication on.  When i enter my username and password, the login fails.  Is there any way to support this without removing the extra security?

Answer (score 5):

For apps that don't support two-factor authentication, such as iMovie, you need to generate an application-specific password. This is a computer generated password that can be used to give an app access to Google services, but is intended for use in a single app.

Go [here](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) to manage your connected apps and application-specific passwords. Once you generate one (be sure to label it as "iMovie password" or similar), copy it into iMovie making sure to use your **full Gmail address** as the "Account Name", then you're done with it.

There's intentionally no way to view the password again, the only possible action is to revoke it. This way your account still stays secure as long as the app stores the password securely (and if it doesn't, you can always revoke that one password without causing problems for the rest of the account).

Comment: Thanks for that. I also found that I needed to tell iMovie my Gmail address, not my YouTube account name.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesButcher, I added that detail to the answer.

Comment: There should also be some backup codes that are generated and listed with instruction of how and when to use them and storing them in a safe place.

Comment: @robmathers, ok, I have the code, but how do you "copy it into iMovie?" It never asks me for a code...